# Hair braid on shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hair

What items should a woman be careful about when trying to make her hair look nice on shabbath? I know braiding the hair is a big no-no. What else can you all tell me?

( In other words, are here any hair styles that are fancy and also kosher for shabbath? )

Answer (score 1):

Brushing hair with a comb that will definitely pull out hair is prohibited, SA [303:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.303.27?lang=bi):

> אסור לסרוק במסרק בשבת ואפי' אותו שעושים משעיר חזיר שא"א שלא יעקרו שערות: (אבל מותר לחוף ולפספס ביד) ב"י)

The Biur Halacha in that siman brings a Rivash that says using oil on the comb after it’s brushed from before, in order to smooth out the hair, (possibly like hair spray) is prohibited because of boneh;

> וכתב הריב"ש שאין כונת רש"י בזה בסריקה דזה אסור משום גוזז ועוד שלא אמרו סורקת במסרק אלא הוא תקון אחר נעשה במסרק ואפשר שהוא התקון שעושין הנערות שאחר שראשן היה סרוק יפה ואין בו חשש של השרת נימין רוחצין המסרק בשמן טרוף במים ומעבירין המסרק על ראשן להדביק השערות זו בזו ולהשכיבן על הראש וזה דומה לבנין עכ"ל

The Tiferes Yisroel in Shabbos 10:35 explains the prohibition of “gadeles” which is an extension of boneh, to include hairlocks or curls;

> כן הגודלת
> שעשתה משערה גדילים (פלעכטען) בל"א או תלתלים (האַאַרלאָקען) בל"א: